# How can I show a FontAwesome spinner on a button?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-5, font-awesome

I have the following HTML using Bootstrap and FontAwesome:

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
         <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" style="display:none;"></i> 
         <i class="fa-solid fa-file-code"></i> HTML
    </button>
```

Using JQuery, I have a click event that should show the i.fa-spinner element:

```
$(".btn").click(function (event) {
    $(".fa-spinner", this)
         .show()
         .attr('style', 'display:inline-block;');

     return true;});
```

This doesn't work--although the source code seems to be updating the style attribute on the i element, it doesn't actually show on the page. If I return false to the click event, it works (the spinner shows), but obviously then the button doesn't submit the form.

I am also doing the same thing with anchor elements, and they work fine.

Any tips? I tried wrapping the i element in a span element and showing/hiding that instead, but it still doesn't work.

I am using Bootstrap 5.1, FontAwesome 6.2.1, and JQuery 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, use the built-in classes i.e. `d-none` (`display: none`).

You can toggle this class on/off, or remove it upon click.

```js
$(".btn").click(function(event) {
  $(this)
    .find(".fa-spinner")
    .removeClass("d-none"); // or $.fn.toggleClass
  return true;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
   <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin d-none"></i> 
   <i class="fa-solid fa-file-code"></i> HTML
</button>
```